# C++ typeid.name() only returns char "c"

Tags: c++, pointers, char, void, typeid

I'm not entirely sure what is going on here. I'm guessing because my input is a string and I'm cycling through it one character at a time it is always returning as type char.

I pretty sure a string is actually char*. The only way I can think to fix this is to include and check what type of character it is, but I'd like to avoid doing that. Is there an alternative method using typeid.name() to figure out what the char is?

I'm using gcc compiler

```
voidQueue outQueue;
string temp = "32ad1f-31f()d";

int i = 0;
while(temp[i] != '\0')
{
    outQueue.enqueue(temp[i]);
    i++;
}

template<typename T>
void voidQueue::enqueue(T data)
{
    T *dataAdded = new T;
    *dataAdded = data;
    string type(typeid(data).name());
    cout<< type;
    myQueue::enqueue((void *)dataAdded,type);
}
```

Comment: Note that `name` returns an implementation-defined string.

Comment: `data` is a `char`. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i want it recognize that char('9') is actually an int

Comment: `typeid` won't tell you anything about the value a `char` holds. You can use `std::isdigit`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want it recognize that char('9') is actually an int

You can use [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) for this:

```
#include <cctype>

bool digit = std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(temp[i]);
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing this, but I think this is the only way that I'll be able to do this. At least for now this is what I'll go with, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `T` is `char` and `gcc` returns `"c"` for `typeid(char).name()`, as demonstrated by the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main() {
  std::cout << typeid(char).name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeid(short).name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeid(int).name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeid(long).name() << std::endl;
}
```

On my compiler, this prints out

```
c
s
i
l
```

Given that the `name()` strings are implementation-defined, this is compliant behaviour.

Comment: Do you know what type it is if it prints out Ph?

Comment: @NPE, do you have a source for the list of these? For example, I am getting "x", but I do not know what it is :-/